# IList<T> version of String.IndexOf (finds a sub-'string', not just a single object)

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I'm looking for an implementation of `List<T>.IndexOf(List<T>)`. I've only found `List<<T>.IndexOf(T)` in the .NET class library.

I have a `List longList` and a `List possibleSubList`. I'd like to know if `possibleSubList` can be found as a sub-'string' within `longList`, and if so, the index into `longList`.

This is basically the same semantics as `System.String.IndexOf`. Anyone know what to call this or if there's a good implementation of it?

Pseudocode Examples:

    `{1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7}.IndexOf({3, 9, 8}) = 2

    {1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7}.IndexOf({1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7}) = 0

    {1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7}.IndexOf({2, 9}) = -1 (not found)`

Clarification: I already have a straightforward implementation of this (two nested for loops), but my lists are rather long, and this is in a performance sensitive area. I'm hoping to find a more efficient implementation than my ~O(m*n).

Comment: Can you give some examples of the expected usage of the function - context and expected results.

Comment: Seems like a good job for a Boyer Moore algorithm but based on `T` instead of `char`. I cant recall complexity but is definitely better than the choices already presented (which look like a brute force method).

Comment: yeah. the naive implementation is pretty straightforward, but I was hoping to find an existing implementation of a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: You should probably change the title to include something about an efficient implementation as it seems that was the main purpose to the question (not just a naive implementation like the one I did)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Linear Z-Indexing** is probably one of the fastest sublist searching algorithm out there today where the pattern is the same and corpus is dynamic, with a true O(n) complexity (with small alphabets, it performs exceptionally better than you might expect from O(n) as ZIndexing provides plenty of opportunities to skip indexes):

I wrote my implementation in a genetics algorithms class under the guidance of Shaojie Zhang from the University of Central Florida.  I've adapted the algorithms to C#, and specifically to use generic `IList<T>`, if you decide to use it, please give credit.  The research for these techniques are available [here](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~shzhang/), and specifically, look at the lecture notes [here](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~shzhang/Combio10/lec3_1.pdf).

**At any rate, I've made the code available [here](https://github.com/dancingplatypus/GeneticAlgorithms.Net)**

Look inside of TestZIndexing.cs for examples of how to perform searches (in this case on character sequences, but using generics you should be able to use anything with an equality operator).

The usage is simple:

```
IEnumerable<int> LinearZIndexer.FindZ<T>(
        IList<T> patternSequence, IList<T> sourceSequence, bool bMatchFirstOnly)
        where T: IComparable;
```

And, as some DNA is circular, I have a circular variant:

```
IEnumerable<int> LinearZIndexer.FindZCircular<T>(
        IList<T> patternSequence, IList<T> sourceSequence, bool bMatchFirstOnly)
        where T: IComparable;
```

Let's do it even faster:  **Suffix Trees**

Alternatively, if you want to get even better performance than O(n), you can get O(m), where m is the size of the pattern list, by using a Suffix Tree.  This works when the pattern changes and the corpus stays the same (the opposite of the previous case).  Look inside the same library I contributed for `TestSuffixTree.cs`.  The only difference here is that you must build the Suffix Tree ahead of time, so it is definitely for multiple pattern searches against a large corpus, but I provide an O(n) and Space(n) algorithm for building that suffix tree.

The calls are equally simple, and again, can use anything that provides an IComparable:

```
string strTest = "bananabananaorangebananaorangebananabananabananaban";
string[] strFind = {"banana", "orange", "ban"};

// I use char, but you can use any class or primitive that 
// supports IComparable

var tree = new SuffixTree<char>();
tree.BuildTree(strTest.ToCharArray());
var results = tree.Find(str.ToCharArray());
foreach(var r in results) Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Use the string search algorithm: (psuedo code)

```
findsubstring(list<T> s, list<T> m){
    for(int i=0; i<s.length;++i)
        for(int j=0; j<m.length;++j)
            if(s[i] != s[j])
                break;
            if(j==m.length-1)
                return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I currently have it written out this way, I'm hoping there's a more efficient implementation than O(N*M). But knowing its called the string search algorithm helps me a lot to look for a better implementation (though I expect them all to hardcode System.String).

Comment: This isn't O(N*M) on avarage. It's actually O(N*p*M) where p is the probability that s[i] == j[0]. But this depends on your data. This is the most optimal algorithm that is availible (AFAIK). The other answer given is worse...

Comment: Hmm, there are faster ways, interesting... Anyway, this algorithm is on avarage O(n+m) as it says on the wikipage you're referring to. What kind of data are you working with?

Comment: @nulvinge the lower bound of this algorithm is O(n+m), which means the first character of the pattern sequence never appeared until the target was found.  The worst case is O(nm) with the average exactly as you stated O(nmp).  At any rate there are much better algorithms for which the upper bound is O(n+m), and with very long sequences, this becomes very significant.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_search#Na.C3.AFve_string_search says avarage is O(n+m). I cannot say anything else because I don't know how your data is built up and how long a "very long sequence" is, but I can say that this algorithm can be implemented to be very fast on a computer. And since it will (probably) be memmory bound, I would dare say that it could be O(n/b) memmory operations (b is blocksize), unless you have some very unrandom data and m<size of cache. (As some trivia: the working part of the innermost loop could partly be implemented as a single instruction on a x86).

Answer (score 1):

I think your use of the word 'sub-string' was a little misleading.  I believe you are trying to see whether a larger list contains a sub-sequence of elements that matches the entire sequence of elements from another list.  This is an extension method that should do what you want it to do, if I understand what you want correctly:

```
public static int IndexOfSequence<T>(this IEnumerable<T> longL, IEnumerable<T> subL)
    {
        var longList = longL.ToList();
        var subList = subL.ToList();

        int longCount = longList.Count;
        int subCount = subList.Count;

        if (subCount > longCount)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        int numTries = longCount - subCount + 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < numTries; i++)
        {
            var newList = new List<T>(longList.Skip(i).Take(subCount));

            if (newList.SequenceEqual(subList))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Then you can use it like:

```
int index = longList.IndexOfSequence(possibleSubList);
```

Comment: It is not recommended to iterate over an IEnumerable more than once. You could call ToList(), or cache the values.

Comment: Hi docmanhattan, I used sub-'string' to avoid confusion with the mathematical definition of sub-sequence (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) which appears in the names of some algorithms like Longest Common Subsequence, and means a pretty different thing.

Comment: @MizardX Thanks, I updated my answer to make it use your advice.

Comment: @Seth Well, I believe you'd have a better chance saying 'subsequence' as sub-string is dealing exclusively with strings and you even got an answer for a string search algorithm :-D

Comment: @docmanhattan agreed. I waffled on that one. I really appreciate your response. As I understand your code though, its still O(m*n) in the worst case. As my longList will be rather long, and this is a performance sensitive operation, I'm hoping for something along the lines of the more efficient algos listed in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: @Seth Are you sure a more clever algorithm is worth it?  It seems like those solutions involve heavy preprocessing.  You could try having the search split up the list into several pieces and searching them in parallel.  Too bad quantum computing isn't far enough yet that we could do all the sequence testing at the same time :-D

Comment: hehheh, agreed ;-) I can afford a lot of pre-processing, which I can cache, but I'm doing a lot of comparisons on pretty long lists, so....

Comment: @Seth Here's a link for a C# implementation of the Boyer-Moore algorithm.  It looks like it should be pretty easy (relatively) to change it from text search to a generic list, or at least get you on the right track. [Fast Text Search with Boyer-Moore](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/fast-text-search-with-boyer-moore)